# Javascript prevent caching without changing script tag

Tags: javascript, caching

i have changed a js file in project but caching mechanism doesn't allow changes to load in browser. I have 170 files that import this js file, so i don't want to change these 170 file
from

```
<script src="/js/*.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/js/*.js?version=1"></script>
```

Is there any other way to prevent caching in browsers?

Comment: Seems like a job for the web server.

Answer (score 0):

The web server can tell the browser how it should be caching files (see http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/). However, if a browser has *already* cached the JS file that you want to replace, the only way to make sure it fetches the new one is to have it fetch from a new URL, hence the "version" cache busting hack. So unfortunately, the answer to your question is "no". grep and/or an IDE's "find and replace" will be your friend here.